# AjaxControlToolkit ReorderList stopped working

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AjaxControlToolkit reorderlist.  all was working well.  then i upgraded the website to .net 4 and visual studio 2010.  Now the reorder is no longer working.  I did some searching and it was suggested to upgrade to the latest version of ajaxtoolcontrol toolkit.  I've put the dll into and it's version 4.1.40412.2.  I've checked the references for the website and it  reads that is is version 4.1.40412.0.  When i run the page, i am not able to drag the icon for the row.  Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

```
<cc1:ReorderList ID="roTask" runat="server" DataKeyField="CJASI_TaskID" SortOrderField="QuestionNo"
                    PostBackOnReorder="false" DragHandleAlignment="Left" Width="97%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="Reorderlist_ItemTemplate">

                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%#databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"Question") %>' />
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlTaskQuestion" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"AddEditTask.aspx?ClassID=" & databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"CJASI_ClassificationID") & "&TaskID=" & databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"CJASI_TaskID") & "&CatID=" & request.querystring("CatID") %>'
                                Text="[Edit]" />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <DragHandleTemplate>
                        <div class="Reorderlist_DragHandleTemplate">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgMove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/imgMove.gif" />
                        </div>
                    </DragHandleTemplate>
                    <ReorderTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ReorderTemplate>
                </cc1:ReorderList>
```

Comment: figured out what my issue was... on the cc1:ReorderList there is a property called clientidmode, it needs to be there and have a value of "AutoID"... hopefully that can help someone else on down the road

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ajax control toolkit 3.5 and visual studio 2010.

Just adding `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` solved the problem.